# import component next js server side to another component (Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)

Tags: next.js

I am testing out a simple next.js react app

> Error is as follows; TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

**server-side.js:**

```
...

export default function Home({books}) {
  
    return (

        <Grid container spacing={2}>            
            {
                books && books.map(row => (
                    <Grid key={row.id} item xs={12} sm={4}>
                       <p>{row.subject}</p>
                    </Grid>
                ))
            }
        </Grid>
        
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {

    const { data } = await client.query({
        query: gql`
            query books{
                books{
                    id
                    subject                 
                  
                }
            }
        `,
    });

    return {
        props: {
            books: data.books,
        },
    };
}
```

---

**index.js:**

```
...
const books= dynamic(
    () => import('./server-side'),
    { loading: () => <div><LinearProgress /></div> }
)

export default function Index() {

    return (
<React.Fragment>
            <books/>
</React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

---

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
> I'm using Next.js. Please see my code below

Comment: As i understand It will not work, The point of dynamic-import is to featch a component /function etc in the client site so the initial js size stays low. You are fetching a whole SSR page, This wont work.

Comment: `getServerSideProps` can only be used on page components - these pages components need to be within the `pages` folder and you can't import them into other components.